# Subquery on JOIN to pulling all ID/Names

Tags: mysql

```
* user
user_id
name

* client
client_id
name

* user_client
user_client_id
user_id
client_id

* message
message_id
client_id
description
```

Sample Table Rows

```
user_id 
1
2
3

client_id   name
10          John
11          James
12          David
13          Richard
14          Bob

user_client
user_id    client_id
1          11
1          13
3          14
3          10

message
message_id    client_id    message
1             11           Hello Word
2             12           MySQL is awesome
3             14           I like StackOverflow
4             13           This is very cool
```

What it's not working is when I use that query as a subquery on a LEFT JOIN to pull the messages only for those clients pertinent to the user.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: So the use case is: select message_id, message, client_id, and name for all messages for all clients of a given user?

Comment: Hi @John that's correct.

Comment: @John the query is working, but the client_id and name are coming as NULL for all but one of the clients... which I can't figure it out why.

Answer (score 0):

The DDL to set up the example (in MySQL) and the query I believe you are looking for are shown below.

```
/*

-- DDL TO SET UP EXAMPLE

create schema example;

use example;

create table user (
    user_id int,
    name varchar(64)
);

create table client(
    client_id int,
    name varchar(64)
);

create table user_client (
    user_client_id int,
    user_id int,
    client_id int
);


create table message(
    message_id int,
    client_id int,
    message varchar(64)
);

insert into user values (1, 'Peter');
insert into user values (2, 'Paul');
insert into user values (3, 'Mary');

insert into client values (10, 'John');
insert into client values (11, 'James');
insert into client values (12, 'David');
insert into client values (13, 'Richard');
insert into client values (14, 'Bob');

insert into user_client values (1, 1, 11);
insert into user_client values (2, 1, 11);
insert into user_client values (3, 3, 14);
insert into user_client values (4, 3, 10);

insert into message values (1, 11, 'Hello World');
insert into message values (2, 12, 'MySQL is awesome');
insert into message values (3, 14, 'I like StackOverflow');
insert into message values (4, 13, 'This is very cool');

*/

-- query to get all messages for all clients of a given user

select 
    *
from
    user_client uc
    join user u on uc.user_id = u.user_id
    join client c on uc.client_id = c.client_id
    join message m on m.client_id = c.client_id
where 
    u.user_id = 1;

-- query to get all messages for a given client

select 
    *
from
    user_client uc
    join user u on uc.user_id = u.user_id
    join client c on uc.client_id = c.client_id
    join message m on m.client_id = c.client_id
where 
    c.client_id = 11;
```

Comment: Hi @John in that case it will show all the messages when the user_client doesn't  contain any entry for a particular user_id?

Answer (score 0):

There was a mistake in my original ddl in one of the inserts (fixed below). In the sql below I've also added a user with no messages.  I believe the query at the end of what is posted below is what you are looking for.

```
-- DDL TO SET UP EXAMPLE

drop schema example;

create schema example;

use example;

create table user (
    user_id int,
    name varchar(64)
);

create table client(
    client_id int,
    name varchar(64)
);

create table user_client (
    user_client_id int,
    user_id int,
    client_id int
);


create table message(
    message_id int,
    client_id int,
    message varchar(64)
);

insert into user values (1, 'Peter');
insert into user values (2, 'Paul');
insert into user values (3, 'Mary');

insert into client values (10, 'John');
insert into client values (11, 'James');
insert into client values (12, 'David');
insert into client values (13, 'Richard');
insert into client values (14, 'Bob');
insert into client values (15, 'Quiet Client');

insert into user_client values (1, 1, 11);
insert into user_client values (2, 1, 13);
insert into user_client values (3, 3, 14);
insert into user_client values (4, 3, 10);
insert into user_client values (5, 1, 15);

insert into message values (1, 11, 'Hello World');
insert into message values (2, 12, 'MySQL is awesome');
insert into message values (4, 13, 'This is very cool');
insert into message values (3, 14, 'I like StackOverflow');

-- query to get all messages for all clients of a given user

select 
    u.user_id,
    u.name user_name,
    c.client_id,
    c.name client_name,
    m.message
from
    user_client uc
    join user u on uc.user_id = u.user_id
    join client c on uc.client_id = c.client_id
    left outer join message m on m.client_id = c.client_id
where 
    u.user_id = 1;
```

Output:

```
+ ------------ + -------------- + -------------- + ---------------- + ------------ +
| user_id      | user_name      | client_id      | client_name      | message      |
+ ------------ + -------------- + -------------- + ---------------- + ------------ +
| 1            | Peter          | 11             | James            | Hello World  |
| 1            | Peter          | 13             | Richard          | This is very cool |
| 1            | Peter          | 15             | Quiet Client     |              |
+ ------------ + -------------- + -------------- + ---------------- + ------------ +
3 rows
```

Comment: Hi @John, thanks for your answer, but when I do user_id = 2 it returns 0 rows when it should return all messages.

Comment: user_id=2 has no clients, therefore no messages. 

(insert order is id, user_id, client_id)
insert into user_client values (1, 1, 11);
insert into user_client values (2, 1, 13);
insert into user_client values (3, 3, 14);
insert into user_client values (4, 3, 10);
insert into user_client values (5, 1, 15);

Why would you expect user_id=2 to return all messages?

The relationship is a message has a client and a client has a user.  Therefore if a user has no clients then the user has no associated messages.

Comment: Hi @John if the user doesn't have any entry on the user_client table, then it has full authorization to view all clients in this scenario.

Comment: So you want a query that will return messages from related clients if there is a record in client, and all messages if there is no record in client for a give user?

Comment: Hi @John that is correct. And that's why I was using the subquery, because it pulls exactly that, but for some reason the client_id and name are coming as NULL for all but one.

Answer (score 0):

This should really be done as three separate queries as three different questions are being asked based on the comments:

> So you want a query that will return messages from related clients if
>   there is a record in client, and all messages if there is no record in
>   client for a give user? –  John

...

> Hi @John that is correct. And that's why I was using the subquery,
>   because it pulls exactly that, but for some reason the client_id and
>   name are coming as NULL for all but one. –  Kitara

The first question (query) is find all of the messages for all of the clients of a given user.

The second question (query) is: Does a user have "authorization" to view all messages. If the user has no clients then that user is "authorized" to view all messages.

The third question (query) is: If the user is authorized to view all messages get all of the messages.

These are very simple straight forward queries to write, execute, and understand.  Trying to conflate all of this into a single query will add complexity and represents poor separation of concerns.  If executing three very simple queries represents a performance issue the architecture of the application needs to be reconsidered.

Comment: thanks I already figure it out what was wrong with query. Thanks